# How do I automatically `layout_below` sequential controls in an Android layout?

Tags: android, layout

I often seem to make Android layouts that have a series of controls that are meant to sit one below the other. For example

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/a"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/b"
        android:layout_below="@+id/a"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/c"
        android:layout_below="@+id/b"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/d"
        android:layout_below="@+id/c"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/e"
        android:layout_below="@+id/d"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

The `android:layout_below` attributes are necessary: without them the TextViews all bunch up together in the same place.

They are also, usually, redundant and a general source of bugs and tedium. As control IDs change, as controls are added and removed, all of these strings must be edited to match up properly. To illustrate the general redundancy of this scheme, note how it promotes this sort of spaghetti:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/e"
        android:layout_below="@+id/d"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/b"
        android:layout_below="@+id/a"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/d"
        android:layout_below="@+id/c"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/a"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/c"
        android:layout_below="@+id/b"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I can see how explicit `layout_below` directives (and friends such as `layout_above`) could be useful in some circumstances. But is there no way of configuring the layout (e.g. the `RelativeLayout`) to simply assume that the each control in the series that it contains should automatically `layout_below` the preceding control?

Comment: If your layout is meant to have series of views one below the other and it involves manipulations, you could try using `LinearLayout` with vertical orientation rather than `RelativeLayout`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[LinearLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.html) might be more suitable for this kind of UI structure. It does exactly what you need, and it does it automatically for you. All that you really have to specify is its `android:orientation` which can be either `vertical` or `horizontal`.

More information on LinearLayout can be found [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/linear.html).

> All children of a LinearLayout
>   are stacked one after the other, so a vertical list will only have one
>   child per row, no matter how wide they are, and a horizontal list will
>   only be one row high (the height of the tallest child, plus padding).

Here's a quick example:

```
<LinearLayout
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:orientation="vertical">

  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/text_view_a"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hey, I'm TextView A!"/>

  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/text_view_b"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hey, I'm TextView B!"/>

  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/text_view_c"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hey, I'm TextView C!"/>

  <!-- ..and so on. -->

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is [LinearLayout](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/linear.html) with a vertical orientation.